# Why is Jesse alarmed to see Cid?

Tags: character, plot-explanation, looper

I am referring to the scene where Jesse, the Gat Man, was releasing Sara who was held at gun-point.

A moment later, Cid can be seen walking down the stairs (*maybe because of the commotion downstairs*). As soon as Jesse senses a figure coming down the stairs, he points the gun at him. In a jiffy he draws his gun back, almost in a surrendering "hands-up" gesture, a look of horror mixed with shock/surprise spread across his face.

**This is his expression on seeing Cid**
[image]

In the ensuing commotion Cid starts to tumble firing up his abnormal TK power.

**This is his reaction when Cid starts to tumble** (*Notice the arms raised in hands up position*)

[image]

Now I can't understand why does Jesse get alarmed on seeing a kid (*assuming he doesn't know who he really is i.e. The Rainmaker*). IMO, a suitable reaction on sensing that its just a kid, would be point the gun back at Joe. **Why the shock and awe?**

Answer (score 8):

Jesse was not just a *hired killer* to say, but he had some morality. He was talking about taking things outside, and was listening to the argument. When Cid comes down, Jesse points the gun at him as a reaction. When Cid sees him, he is startled and slips and falls down the stairs.

Jesse is surprised because Cid is just a boy and he did not want to point the gun on a kid. Also, he is slightly horrified that he startled Cid into him falling down the stairs. That's why he hastily took down his gun.

Per se, Jesse was an enforcer, not a bad guy.

Comment: Granted, Jesse was not a bad guy by any means. But the look on Jesse's face starts to transpire even before Cid makes the fall and not after it.

Comment: startled to see a kid, he didnt want to scar the child maybe?